# Regular expression to match a price

Tags: python, regex

Here are the requirements for regular expression:

- There can be a space before or after
- There will be a dollar sign "$" either before or after
- Sometimes, instead of dollar sign, there could be a string "dollar"

Examples to match:

```
$342
 $322
232$
2323dollar
```

Comment: That's an interesting challenge! What have you tried so far?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I am using Python. I have tried this: \$?(\d+)\$?. But I cannot satisfy the third requirement: that instead of dollar sign I may have "dollar" string

Comment: Can there be decimal numbers, as in `123.45$`? Can there also be a space between the `$`/`dollar` and the number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?:\$|dollar)(\d+)|(\d+)(?:\$|dollar)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dK1xR4/2

Comment: awesome. Thank you very much. I will accept your answer shortly

Comment: His regex (which was buried in a comment) may not, but his specification says explicitly `There will be a dollar sign "$" either before or after`

Comment: one problem here: "70$ is the cost of this product". The regex does not catch 70$ ((

Comment: I think that if he's only looking for substrings, we don't need the `\s*?`s any more.

Comment: @TimPietzcker you were right. I need to find the match only when the digit and $ or dollar come together. That is, I don't need 123. I need 123$. Can you help me?

Comment: @TimPietzcker one more question. Do you know if django cares encoding while doing regex. The case in point: instead of "dollar", I am using russian currency. The regex is working fine in regex101.com but django is ignoring the russian characters.

Comment: @DieSeLinho: `\$` matches `$` and nothing else. There is no magical regex token for "any currency symbol". You need to specify exactly which characters/texts are expected and build the regex accordingly.

Comment: @TimPietzcker I am trying to print group(0) from the result. It gives me nothing. How do I get the whole matched string?